# How to get the value of asp file upload in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to get the value of asp fileupload in javascript. I tried but wouldnt able to get the value of two file uploads.

```
function alertupload() {>  
             var firstvalue = document.getElementById("ctl01_uxPlaceHolder_uxProductFormView_ctl01_uxOptionGroupDetails_uxOptionDataList_ctl00_uxOptionItemDetails_uxOptionUploadItem_uxUploadFile").value;

             var backvalue = document.getElementById("ctl01_uxPlaceHolder_uxProductFormView_ctl01_uxOptionGroupDetails_uxOptionDataList_ctl01_uxOptionItemDetails_uxOptionUploadItem_uxUploadFile").value;

            alert(frontvalue);
            alert(backvalue);              

 }
```

Comment: if `ctl01_uxPlaceHolder_uxProductFormView_ctl01_uxOptionGroupDetails_uxOptionDataList_ctl00_uxOptionItemDetails_uxOptionUploadItem_uxUploadFile` the id then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If `ctl01_uxPlaceHolder_uxProductFormView_ctl01_uxOptionGroupDetails_uxOptionDataLi‌​st_ctl00_uxOptionItemDetails_uxOptionUploadItem_uxUploadFile` the id then it should work.

Other wise use client Id

```
var firstvalue = document.getElementById("<%= uxUploadFile.ClientID %>");
alert(firstvalue);
```

Comment: The question is I am using the javascript in master page and the asp fileupload is inside a usercontrol. But I can't able to get the value in master page.

Comment: var firstvalue = document.getElementById("<%= uxUploadFile.ClientID %>");
alert(firstvalue);